# How to properly setup GNOME VNC session on CentOS 7?

Tags: gnome, vnc

I am trying to run a xvnc (`Xvnc TigerVNC 1.8.0 - built Aug  9 2019 03:04:19` to be exact) session on CentOS 7 on port 80.

I have installed gnome-desktop using `yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop"` and then installed TigerVNC. 
My log:

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.8.0 - built Aug  9 2019 03:04:19
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12001000, The X.Org Foundation


Fri Feb 28 09:40:04 2020
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 80
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
/root/.vnc/xstartup: line 12: x-terminal-emulator: command not found

Fri Feb 28 09:40:07 2020
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)

Fri Feb 28 09:48:04 2020
 Connections: accepted: <IPHERE>::36796
 Connections: closed: <IPHERE>::36796 (reading version failed: not an RFB
              client?)
 EncodeManager: Framebuffer updates: 0
 EncodeManager:   Total: 0 rects, 0 pixels
 EncodeManager:          0 B (1:-nan ratio)
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
```

My xstartup:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
exec gnome-session &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
# x-window-manager &
```